# How to make device to support telugu language

Tags: android, keyboard

I installed telugu fonts in system/fonts directory. And i made keyboard for telugu.when i type telugu letters in that keyboard it will show like this [][][][] .Only it is showing boxes.i run it in 4.3 emulator.what i should do to bring telugu letters by using telugu keyboard whcih i made

Comment: i think you should change in mobile/simulator settings language...

Comment: in settings language, there is no option for telugu language

Answer (score 2):

**Step-1**
create fonts directory inside assets directory

**Step-2**
Download proper font of desired language (in ttf format)

**step-3**
Save the above ttf file inside fonts directory

**step-4**
create typeface object programmetically using following code

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/telugu.ttf");
```

Comment: everything i have done what you said above but it is showing like that boxes

Comment: try with some other language. in order to check whether the ttf file is proper or not?

Comment: first emulator 4.3 os will support telugu language?.....if it supports it will work but there is no  option for supporting that language.is there any option for supporting that language?